# insert data in a row with undefined values in each row

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with few columns `Name,stage1, stage2, stage3, stage4, stage5`. Now I want to insert values into these columns, but every time when a new row is being inserted into the table, the number of stages to be entered under each row is undefined For Example:-

Suppose in row 1 values for stage1 and stage2 are defined, and for row 2 values for stage1, stage2, stage3 and stage4 are defined and so on

Problem
I am not able to insert a new row in the table because of the uneven distribution of values for each name.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information.  For example, how do you not know what you're inserting?  In addition, your table structure looks... poor.  Do you really have only 5 columns like that?  If so, you should consider properly normalizing your database.  Doing so will help prevent future problems that result from poor design.

Comment: I agree with @DeadZone 100%. Your structure has repeating columns which is just awful to work with. As you are finding just inserting the 4th element is difficult. This is a design you need to rebuild. Consider what happens when your application is working and you need to add a 6th stage. You will have to edit everything. If you have properly normalized data structures it is as simple as adding a new row.

Comment: so what I have to do

Comment: Can you provide some example data? You can re-work your data structure to insert a consistent number of values, each representing only one data element but it starts with looking at example data in your current data structure.

Comment: You cannot do this. *Either* you have an `INSERT` that inserts values (possibly `NULL`) into **all** columns of a table, or then you need to **specify** what columns to insert into - you cannot insert into "unknown" or "unnamed" columns ...

Comment: see my answer. From you screen shot this looks like typical parent/child data. your stages should be rows in a child table that is related to the header data. This is no different from InvoiceHeader / DetailLines type structure.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to use a Relational database for unstructured data. I assume this because you tagged SQL Server.

This is what document dbs or noSQL dbs were designed for.

However, you can emulate this if you want by storing the data in a single column. Within that column you can store either JSON or XML. JSON is going to be hard to query, but SQL Server does support an XML field type that you can query with XPath.

The other option is to rotate your data 90 degrees. Instead of each stage being a column stage1, stage2, stage3.... create a row for each stage. Each row would have a stageNumber field or some such. You could later pivot this data to display it with stages as columns in Excel or some other pivot table or whatever.